# Select count/sum with multiple like and as query group by year/date?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having problem solving Select Count data from multiple table.

I have "rent" table as transaction table, like this
[image: rent]

And "customer" table as master table [image: customer]

And here's my current query

```
select 

ifnull((SELECT COUNT(rent_id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(rent_date)=1)AND (YEAR(rent_date)='2017'))),0) AS `Jan`,
      ifnull((SELECT COUNT(rent_id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(rent_date)=2)AND (YEAR(rent_date)='2017'))),0) AS `Feb`,
      ifnull((SELECT COUNT(rent_id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(rent_date)=3)AND (YEAR(rent_date)='2017'))),0) AS `Mar`,
      ifnull((SELECT COUNT(rent_id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(rent_date)=4)AND (YEAR(rent_date)='2017'))),0) AS `Apr`,
      ifnull((SELECT COUNT(rent_id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(rent_date)=5)AND (YEAR(rent_date)='2017'))),0) AS `May`,
      ifnull((SELECT COUNT(rent_id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(rent_date)=6)AND (YEAR(rent_date)='2017'))),0) AS `Jun`,
      ifnull((SELECT COUNT(rent_id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(rent_date)=7)AND (YEAR(rent_date)='2017'))),0) AS `Jul`,
      ifnull((SELECT COUNT(rent_id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(rent_date)=8)AND (YEAR(rent_date)='2017'))),0) AS `Aug`,
      ifnull((SELECT COUNT(rent_id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(rent_date)=9)AND (YEAR(rent_date)='2017'))),0) AS `Sep`,
      ifnull((SELECT COUNT(rent_id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(rent_date)=10)AND (YEAR(rent_date)='2017'))),0) AS `Oct`,
      ifnull((SELECT COUNT(rent_id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(rent_date)=11)AND (YEAR(rent_date)='2017'))),0) AS `Nov`,
      ifnull((SELECT COUNT(rent_id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(rent_date)=12)AND (YEAR(rent_date)='2017'))),0) AS `Dec`
     from transaction 
     where YEAR(rent_date)='2017'
    GROUP BY YEAR(rent_date)
```

The result query above in my project is like this

```
+-----------+----------+
| Month     | Rent     |
+-----------+----------+
|       Aug |        4 | 
|       Sep |        4 | 
+-----------+----------+
```

And I want to change the result like this

```
+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| Month     | S        | SS        | SSS      |
+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
|       Aug |        2 |          1|        1 | 
|       Sep |        2 |          1|        1 | 
+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

The S, SS and SSS column data are from COUNT rent_id which selected from customer_status in customer table.

What changes I must made for those result?
I don't know where I should put JOIN, AS and LIKE
Or there's easier way to get these result

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: The result you posted surely is not produced by the query you posted.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query